# ¿Cómo puedo convertir la siguiente respuesta Json en un objeto C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

```
{
    "payment": [
        {

        "processorFields": [
            {
                "keyword": "credit",
                "value": {
                    "code": "1",
                    "type": "03",
                    "groupCode": "X",
                    "installments": "12"
                },
                "displayOn": "none"
            },
            {
                "keyword": "totalAmount",
                "value": 56.1,
                "displayOn": "none"
            },
            {
                "keyword": "interestAmount",
                "value": 1.1,
                "displayOn": "none"
            },
            {
                "keyword": "installmentAmount",
                "value": 4.675,
                "displayOn": "none"
            },
            {
                "keyword": "iceAmount",
                "value": 0,
                "displayOn": "none"
            },
            {
                "keyword": "lastDigits",
                "value": "0008",
                "displayOn": "none"
            }
         ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Necesito guardar en variables los valores que me da el json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer paso que recomendaria es que uses

http://json2csharp.com/

para conseguir las clases en c# que mepan con el json que tienes, podria ser algo como esto

```
public class ProcessorField
{
    public string keyword { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
    public string displayOn { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public List<ProcessorField> processorFields { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Payment> payment { get; set; }
}
```

despues usarias la libreria json.net para deserializar, puedes agregar la referencia usando nuget

[Newtonsoft.Json nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

entonces seria

```
string json = @"..."; //aqui pones el json

RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio muco :), era justo lo que necesitaba